# MDX: How to replace null value

Tags: ssas, mdx, msbi

[image]

How to replace null values in mdx.

Comment: I think this has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851274/mdx-how-to-replace-null-values-with-0-in-measures-members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].ComputerSalesNew AS
    iif(
       isempty([Measures].ComputerSales),
       0,
       [Measures].ComputerSales
    )
```

Comment: hi @whtheq- can u please answer the below question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282243/mdx-i-need-column-count-based-on-the-total-rows